# <video>タグでバイナリデータ表示

Tags: javascript, php, html

MYSQlから取得した動画のバイナリデーターを
`<Video>`で再生したいのですが、可能ですか？

Answer (score 1):

可能と思います。
色々、サーバの制限など考慮しないといけないと思いますが、サーバ側がphpなら こんなかんじでしょうか。

```
<video><source src="hoge.php" type="video/mp4"></source></video>
```

hoge.phpでの処理はこんなかんじでしょうか

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `data`";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
//video/mp4
    header("Content-type: video/mp4");
    echo row[2];
}
```

Comment: 編集画面でコード部分を範囲選択し、エディタの上の方にある`{}`ボタンを押すとコードを装飾できます。不等号記号もそうするとうまく表示されます。また、コードでない部分に出てくる不等号記号については`&lt;`などのエスケープが使えます。

Answer (score 0):

CGIをvideo系のMIMEタイプでバイナリをそのまま出すものと、HTMLを吐くものに分けて、
前者のURLを後者がvideoタグのsrc属性に指定して返せば良いでしょう。

Answer (score -1):

こんな感じでいかがでしょうか。

```
function display_video(){
    $video = 'play.mp4';
    try {
        $db = new PDO($dbconnect, $db_user, $db_password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    if (($result = $db->query('SELECT video FROM videos WHERE `name` = "'.$video.'"')) !== false)
    {
        echo '<div content="Content-Type: video/mp4">
                  <video width="600" height="480" controls="controls" poster="image" preload="metadata">
                  <source src="data:video/mp4;base64,'.base64_encode($result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)).'"/>;
              </video>
          </div>';
    }
    else 
    {
        // 失敗した際の処理
    }
}
```